# pytest-html with PyCharm - Debug fails but Run works

Tags: pytest, playwright, pytest-html

Getting error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest_html.plugin'; 'pytest_html' is not a package only during debug but running the test case works.
I printed sys.executable which during run and debug prints the same.
uninstalling pytest_html and commenting lines reg `pytest_html_results_table_row` works fine.
Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your code and all relevant versions (packages, Python, OS). Thanks.